# Phalcon does not load under nginx and php5-fpm

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I've tried putting `extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/phalcon.so` into `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`, when it didn't work, I've put that into `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` as well and when that didn't work either, I've finally put that into `/etc/php5/mods-availavle/phalcon.ini` and it still didn't work. **I restarted both php5-fpm and nginx after each change. I've also tried with and without path**

I'm on ubuntu 14.04 but I had same problem with 12.04

Comment: does the file `/usr/lib/php5/20121212/phalcon.so` exist?

Comment: Okay, I fixed. Yeah @masegaloeh, it exists. Thanks for trying to help me!

FIX: Do not insert extension=phalcon.so in php.ini, but create file named 21-phalcon.ini in /etc/php5/fpm/config.d. The reason is Phalcon must be loaded AFTER pdo. PDO is loaded with priority 20, so anything after 20 will work

Comment: Stefan, if this is what ended up helping you, could you answer your question and accept it? That way future visitors with the same issue will see the answer more obviously :)